# how can upload an excel file in php and print the content in html table?

Tags: php, html, phpexcel

i try to use phpoffice/phpexcel to do this but i haven't an idea of do it... i have this form in html

```
<body>
    <div align="center">ELENCA TABELLE PRESENTI NEL DB</div>
        <form action="index.php" method="post"
        enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Filename:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="right">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="/include/js/bootstrap-contextmenu.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/include/js/bootflat.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/s/bs/pdfmake-0.1.18,dt-1.10.10,af-2.1.0,b-1.1.0,b-colvis-1.1.0,b-html5-1.1.0,b-print-1.1.0,cr-1.3.0,fc-3.2.0,fh-3.1.0,kt-2.1.0,r-2.0.0,rr-1.1.0,sc-1.4.0,se-1.1.0/datatables.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

i want use it for upload an excel file and in another file call index.php, i want do a query for show the data into this excel file that i have upload in a html table, how can i do this? thank you very much

i have just installed the package phpoffice/phpexcel with composer, i can use the libraries into this

Comment: You're asking a php specific question (regarding the use of those libraries) without showing any php code. What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.